# Finding most frequent element and sorting data

Tags: python, sorting, csv, pandas, group-by

I have a large csv file that I want to convert into a table with the pertinent information.

It is something like this:

```
ComplaintNumber;CompanyName;CallerName;EmpName;CallStatus;Gen_Code;Detail Code;OtherDetail;CallDesc;QualityIssue;HighPriority;Received Data and Time; Call Type;count;Unnamed: 14;Unnamed: 15;Unnamed: 16;Unnamed: 17;Unnamed: 18;Unnamed: 19;Unnamed: 20;Unnamed: 21;Unnamed: 22;Unnamed: 23   
5651;Company 1;joe;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 1;;Sentence that is relatively long but not too long;No;1-No;6/11/2015 15:00;Type 1;8;;;;;;;;;;  
6642;Company 1;joe;Rob;Closed;Support;Code 2;;another sentence that is relatively long but not too long;No;1-No;6/12/2015 15:00;Type 2;8;;;;;;;;;;  
6893;Company 1;joe;Rob;Closed;Support;Code 2;;description and stuff;No;1-No;6/13/2015 15:00;Type 3;8;;;;;;;;;;  
4535;Company 1;joe;Gwen;Closed;Maintenance;Code 4;;So and so called and said such and such;No;1-No;6/14/2015 15:00;Type 2;8;;;;;;;;;;   
8655;Company 1;joe;Gwen;Closed;Support;Code 56;;Somebody needs a nap     apparently;No;1-No;6/15/2015 15:00;Type 1;8;;;;;;;;;;
8656;Company 1;joe;Wendy;Closed;Computer;Code 12;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/12/2015 15:00;Type 1;8;;;;;;;;;;
8857;Company 1;joe;Sarah;Closed;Computer;Code 3;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/17/2015 15:00;Type 4;8;;;;;;;;;;
3348;Company 1;joe;John;Closed;Computer;Code;Red;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/18/2015 15:00;Type 4;8;;;;;;;;;;
6679;Company 2;Belinda;John;Closed;Maintenance;Code 4;;Yup   just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/4/2015 19:00;Type 4;7;;;;;;;;;;
5510;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 1;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;;6/20/2015 15:00;Type 4;7;;;;;;;;;;
7711;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 1;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/21/2015 12:00;Type 4;7;;;;;;;;;;
6212;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 4;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/22/2015 15:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
4413;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 34;;Yup   just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/23/2015 5:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
1444;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 2;Blue;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/23/2015 15:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
5515;Company 2;Rodger;Yolanda;Closed;Maintenance;Code 1;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/25/2015 15:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
1756;Company 3;Janet;Yolanda;Closed;Maintenance;Code 2;;Yup  just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/26/2015 15:00;Type 2;5;;;;;;;;;;
1557;Company 3;Janet;Yolanda;Closed;Computer;Code 4 ;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/27/2015 15:00;Type 2;5;;;;;;;;;;
1238;Company 3;Janet;Yolanda;Closed;Computer;Code 45;Purple;Yup  just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/28/2015 15:00;Type 1;5;;;;;;;;;;
1729;Company 3;Richard;Steve;Closed;Computer;Code 2 ;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/29/2015 15:00;Type 1;5;;;;;;;;;;
2340;Company 3;Richard;Fred;Closed;Support;Code 4;Yellow;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/30/2015 15:00;Type 3;5;;;;;;;;;;
2131;Company 4;Pamela;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 5;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/1/2015 15:00;Type 3;3;;;;;;;;;;
2662;Company 4;Pamela;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 6;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/2/2015 15:00;Type 3;3;;;;;;;;;;
2833;Company 4;Pamela;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 7;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/3/2015 15:00;Type 3;3;;;;;;;;;;
2564;Company 5;Stan;Steve;Closed;Computer;Code 8;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/4/2015 15:00;Type 3;1;;;;;;;;;;
2225;Company 6;Lee;Steve;Closed;Computer;Code 9;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/5/2015 15:00;Type 4;1;;;;;;;;;;
1326;Company 7;Jackie;Steven;Closed;Support;Code 10;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/6/2015 15:00;Type 1;1;;;;;;;;;;
7227;Company 8;Jake;Rob;Closed;Support;Code 11;;Yup  just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/7/2015 15:00;Type 2;1;;;;;;;;;;
4228;Company 9 ;Steve;Wendy;Closed;Computer;Code 12;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/8/2015 15:00;Type 3;1;;;;;;;;;;
```

I want to make a table that has the top five callers as headings and underneath the EmpName (whoever took the most calls from that customer), the Gen_code, and a sentence from the *most recent* (the calls also have a date and time received column) CallDesc.

Output will be laid out like this table (obviously with different inputs)
[image]

I would appreciate even just guidance on how to approach this problem. Pseudocode is fine. Even better if there's a quick, easy way!

So far I've sorted my list so that the customers that show up with the most frequency are at the top of the list. But from there I don't know how to get the most recent call description or even how to just select the top five.

Comment: Open in the file in a text editor (not excel), and paste some in as code.

Comment: @LiamFoley Like that?

Comment: It is really hard to solve your example because there is no clear delimiter between the fields. You could use df.to_csv() and post that ;)

Comment: Happy to do that, but a little lost. It is already in a csv but when I copy it over it doesn't keep commas as delimiters. How do I retain them?

Comment: Use notepad to open the csv

Comment: @Gecko it should be tab delimited now. Thanks!

Comment: It is not tab-delimited. Maybe it is being removed somewhere in the pipeline. You marked the question with a pandas tag, so I assume you can create a DataFrame from it. In that case you can just use the .to_csv( sep= '; ') method to ensure you get a semicolon as delimiter.

Comment: @Gecko did this work? Sorry, this is getting annoying, I know. I'm not sure why it added Unnamed Columns and a ton of semicolons at the end but hopefully that's enough to play around with?

Answer (score 0):

How about

Sort by callers `.sort('callers', ascending = False)`

Set callers as index `.set_index('callers')`

Select the other columns that interest you

Transpose `.T`

Comment: I think the thing I'm most struggling with is picking the top five customers (they're already sorted similar to the example, where counts is the number of times they've called in) and finding the most recent call description. Maybe I need to do some for loops?

Answer (score 0):

This might be cleanest/fastest when performed in SQL, as long is that's something you feel comfortable with.  Assuming you've created a table with your data, this query would give you the top 5 customers:

```
create temporary table top_5 as 
    select * from (select CallerName,max(count) as num_calls 
    from complaints group by CallerName) order by num_calls desc limit 5;


select CallerName, num_calls,
(select EmpName from complaints where CallerName=c.CallerName order by count desc limit 1) as top_employee, 
(select CallDesc from complaints where CallerName=c.CallerName order by Received_Data_and_Time desc limit 1) as recent_desc, 
(select Gen_code from complaints where CallerName=c.CallerName order by Received_Data_and_Time desc limit 1) as recent_gencode 
from complaints c join top_5 on top_5.CallerName=c.CallerName;
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure the dates can be ordered the correct way when input into the db, or you can use some kind of string to date parse function from whichever database you want to use. Sqlite is probably my preference and fits nicely with most reporting-style tasks, as long as you're not reporting on complaints to Comcast over the last 20 years.

Comment: Interesting, I've never used SQL before, but I'll try this (probably using Access) Thanks for the input!